# Tabular in frame: get rid of horizontal spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, framed

I'm trying to surround a tabular with a thick frame:

```
\setlength\fboxrule{2pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{2cm}|p{2cm}@{}}
        A & B \\ \hline
        C & D \
    \end{tabular}
}
```

Although I set `\fboxsep` to `0pt` and use `@{}`, there is *still* some horizontal margin between the frame and the tabular:

http://flyx.org/files/framedtabular.png

I want the horizontal line to reach the frame at both ends. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are a victim of end of line space. Put `%` as shown in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \setlength\fboxrule{2pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{%    %% <------- here
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{2cm}|p{2cm}@{}}
        A & B \\ \hline
        C & D 
    \end{tabular}%   %% <------- here
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details on adding `%` at the end refer to [This Q and its A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines).

Comment: It's copied from the OP but that `\ ` after `D` looks wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You have very good eyes. Thanks and corrected. :)